# Output all invoices this month

Tags: sql, oracle

I looking to pull all the invoices that have been posted the month the report gets run. It must be simple, something I am overlooking. I am on an ORACLE database.

I am thinking:

```
Select * from Invoice inv 
WHERE inv.post_date between to_date ('FIRST_OF_THE_MONTH', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                        and to_date ('LAST_OF_THE_MONTH',  'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

of course, `FIRST_OF_THE_MONTH` and `LAST_OF_THE_MONTH` are not real things. right?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be very careful when working with `date`s in databases and in Oracle in particular.  Oracle has a time component as part of the `date` data type.  For this reason, you should avoid `between`.

Instead, write the logic as:

```
select i.*
from Invoice i 
where i.post_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MON') and
      i.post_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), 1);
```

This logic works regardless of whether `post_date` has a time component or not, so it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last of the current month, you can use `TRUNC` and `SYSDATE` to get the start of the month. You could do:

```
Select * from Invoice inv 
WHERE inv.post_date between TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MONTH' )
                        and ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MONTH' ) + 1 )
```